# Set value obtained from javascript code in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a model named "AdvancedSearchViewModel" in which I am setting few values using Form.post method from view page but the same time I have to send one more value in the same model which is being obtained from script.
In given code I have to set "datevalue" in "AdvancedSearchViewModel" model.

```
var createDate = $('#ModifiedDate').val();
    createDate = createDate.toLowerCase();
    var sd = new moment("february 26, 2014");
    var regex = /(\d+)/g;
    var t = dateTime(createDate);
  var datevalue=sd.subtract(t, createDate.match(regex));
```

Comment: you can use hidden input fields, set the value of the hidden field in to datevalue here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden input element inside the form and using javascript assign the datevalue to it.
On form post this data will also go to the controller.

Ex:
in .cshtml file:
 2

javascript:

$("#date").val(datevalue);